# Server Connectivity Issue

Tags: networking, routing, esxi, vcenter

This question is an extension of my previous question that is on hold at Server Fault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/840611/issues-adding-esxi-host-to-vcenter-server). I have done some further troubleshooting, and have found out the following through pings and packet captures:

1) The ESXi host is able to ping the pfSense router successfully. When I then try to ping the vCenter server, the ping does not receive a reply on the network.

2) The vCenter server is able to ping the pfsense router as well. When the vCenter server pings the ESXi host, a ping request *and a ping reply* is seen on the network, however there is 100% packet loss on the vCenter server.

It seems to me that at some point during the transmission to the vCenter server, traffic must be sent to the wrong place or the traffic must be blocked.

I have compared network settings of the two hosts, and the setup between the host that works and the host that can't be added is the same. The re-image of the problematic host also leaves me to believe that there is no issue with the host configuration.

I am unsure how to proceed from here as there isn't any firewall or routing configurations in pfSense that would cause these issues. Is there a firewall built in to vCenter or ESXi that I don't know about? Is there any caches that I should try clearing on a specific machine? Please let me know what other information I should collect.

**Edit 1:**
It seems that the ARP table of the vCenter server has an entry for the host that is connected, but not the host that won't connect.

Comment: A few quick things... look for firmware updates to start... and look over this [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2582281/slow-failover-operation-if-no-router-exists-between-the-cluster-and-an-application-server) in case it applies... look over this [VMQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2986895/virtual-machines-lose-network-connectivity-when-you-use-broadcom-netxtreme-1-gigabit-network-adapters) post in case it applies.... lastly have a look at https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003804

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator The hotfix doesn't apply since this is a vCSA deployment. The VMQ is a non-issue as well. I used the command `no spanning-tree vlan 103` (since I only have one switch anyway) and it still doesn't connect.